# How to read, write file over gwan

Tags: g-wan

I am new to gwan, and currently coding a read/write static file over gwan, however, I found that when I try to open file (corresponding to some parameter pass to gwan), it run the main() twice (or infinite looping), could any one help ? Thanks!

Here is the getanddelivery.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    global_count = 1;
    printf("Global count : %d\n", global_count);

    xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
    char *name = 0;

    while(global_count<argc){
            get_arg("zoneid=", &name, global_count, argv);

          if(hadCache(name)){
                    printf("have file\n");
          }else{
                    printf("No file found!\n");
          }
            global_count++;
    }

    xbuf_xcat(reply, "Work!");

    return 200;

}
```

Function hadCache is to check whether the static file exist or not!
Thanks again!!

---

Thank you Gil for answering my question! I had modified the code and it work now!
However, I try to use my own header file and function file on gwan under gwan/include/myownfunction.h & hadCache.c, I found that the getanddelivery.c cannot normally call the hadCache() function

```
#include "myownfunction.h"

int main(){ ... }
```

myownfunction.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool hadCache(char* zoneid);
```

hadCache.c

```
#include "myownfunction.h"

bool hadCache(char* zoneid){...}
```

However, it work if I replace this on my getanddelivery file:

```
Replace this #include "myownfunction.h"
By           #include "hadCache.c"
```

Could you please help me ? Thank you v much !

Comment: Oh, I found that the un-predictable result is caused by the cache file, I havent create some of the cache files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the thread-unsafe **global_count++;** variable increment which will cause havock under concurrency.

You should rather read about **atomicity** and use an atomic incrementation. See this other question: [feature request: an atomicAdd() function included in gwan.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302161/feature-request-an-atomicadd-function-included-in-gwan-h/13308542#13308542).